# Power function with negative values in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to use Power(a,b) function in hive query.

Whenever b is negative value, the power function results in incorrect value.

This is happening only if parameters in power function are negative. Please help.

Comment: Voted to close. I see no issue with negative exponent. e.g. `select power (2,-3)` returns `0.12`. If you still thinks there is an issue - show an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily calculate negative exponent. Calculate positive exponent and take the reciprocal:

```
power(a,-b) = 1/power(a,b)
```

See the explanation here: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/negative-exponents.html

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz Yes, it works. Could not find where this issue was fixed... And in which version was it really exist. But documentation says "Power(decimal, n) only supports positive integer values for the exponent n." here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types